# Selecting the first directory using Regex Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an input of the form`./Simple Root/Test/Thing/Test/Thing/`. How do I select the the first sub directory? Where my answer would be

**Case 1:**
Simple Root

**Case 2:**
/Simple Root/

My attempt `\/(.+)\/` selects the whole string! Please help me out.Thanks!

Comment: You can use `split` something like... `var arr= str.split('/'); alert(arr[1]);`

Comment: Yes, I've thought of that but I want to practice my regex skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use non-greedy version of `.+`: `.+?`:

case 1:

```
'./Simple Root/Test/Thing/Test/Thing/'.match(/\/.+?\//)
// => ["/Simple Root/"]
'./Simple Root/Test/Thing/Test/Thing/'.match(/\/.+?\//)[0]
// => "/Simple Root/"
```

case 2:

```
'./Simple Root/Test/Thing/Test/Thing/'.match(/\/(.+?)\//)
// => ["/Simple Root/", "Simple Root"]
'./Simple Root/Test/Thing/Test/Thing/'.match(/\/(.+?)\//)[1]
// => "Simple Root"
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Works like a charm. What exactly does '?' do? That seems to be he only additional thing that you have done

Comment: @SaiKrishnaDeep, by default `.+` or `.*` match as much as possible (greedy). Appending `?` prevent that.

Comment: match(/\/(.+?)\//)[1] seems to give an 'undefined' error when I try to alert. Any idea why?

Comment: @SaiKrishnaDeep, With which string did you call it? If the string does not match, `match` method will return `null`. You need to check it.

Comment: @SaiKrishnaDeep, You missed `(..)` (capturing group). See the forked version: http://jsfiddle.net/tsvbdsj1/

Comment: What change do i have to make in order to match  just './Simple Root' without the second forward slash!

Comment: @SaiKrishnaDeep, Including `.`?

Comment: Yes, whatever the characters are present

Comment: @SaiKrishnaDeep, Try: `'./Simple Root/Test/Thing/Test/Thing/'.match('^[^/]*/[^/]+')`  (`[^/]` match any character that is not `/`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var dir = "./Simple Root/Test/Thing/Test/Thing/".match(/^.*?\/(.*?)\//);
alert(dir[1]);
```

Check https://regex101.com/r/pM7sF9/1